# Build failure with CMake / Android NDK / sdkmanager

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

I have been trying to compile a C library for Android armeabi-v7a using the following setup:

- Ubuntu
- CMake 3.22
- Android cmdline-tools 10406996_latest

Then I used sdkmanager to install

- build-tools 34.0.0
- platforms android-34
- platform-tools
- ndk 26.1.10909125

All that can be found in `/opt/android/` and `/opt/android/ndk` ...

I'm using a CMakeLists.txt file which contains the following bits of configuration:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)

set(ANDROID_NDK_VERSION "26.1.10909125")
set(ANDROID_ABI "armeabi-v7a")
set(ANDROID_HOME "/opt/android")
set(ANDROID_NDK "${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk/${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}")
set(ANDROID_PLATFORM "android-34")
set(ANDROID_ARM_NEON ON)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 34)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI "${ANDROID_ABI}")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "${ANDROID_NDK}")
```

And CMake generation fails with the following error:

```
-- Android: Targeting API '34' with architecture 'arm', ABI 'armeabi-v7a', and processor 'armv7-a'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/Platform/Android-Initialize.cmake:97 (message):
  Android: The system root directory needed for the selected Android version
  and architecture does not exist:

    /opt/android/ndk/26.1.10909125/platforms/android-34/arch-arm

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInitialize.cmake:21 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)
```

What I don't get is why CMake is looking for the `platforms` dir in `ndk` when `sdkmanager` seems to install everything at the root of `ANDROID_HOME` (e.g. `/opt/android`). Also there doesn't seem to be any `arch-arm` dir in `/opt/android/platforms/android-34`...

Any know incompatibility with these versions? Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is default selection of CMAKE_SYSROOT for Android toolchain: `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}/arch-${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH}")` ([Modules/Platform/Android-Initialize.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Android-Initialize.cmake#L91)). If you think that given sysroot directory is wrong, you may assign correct value to the variable in your script.

Comment: "I'm using a CMakeLists.txt file which contains the following bits of configuration" - Setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and other variables in `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong. Instead, prepare your own **toolchain file** and pass path to it in `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable. In your toolchain file you could `include()` the base toolchain. Alternatively, you may create a [CMake preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) which defines all these variables and specifies `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable pointed to the "base" toolchain script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "Setting CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME and other variables in CMakeLists.txt is wrong. Instead, prepare your own toolchain file and pass path to it in CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable" - Yes, I made a bit of a shortcut when describing my setup, it's actually a toolchain file I extracted the config from.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "In your toolchain file you could include() the base toolchain." - That might be it. I wasn't sure it would be a good idea to include a toolchain file in another toolchain file so, initially, I just overwrote the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE var. But using include() instead sort of fixed the initial error... I'll post the solution when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Tsyvarev's advice, replacing:

`set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake")`

... by:

`ìnclude("${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake")`

... did the trick for me.